# Word or phrase for saying you don't want something when you really do

Tags: word-choice

Like if I offer somebody a candy bar and they say "no thank you" when they actually would love to eat it.

I've heard people refer to it as "being modest", but the dictionary definition of modest doesn't seem to match very well.

Comment: _Reticent:_ Not revealing one’s thoughts or feelings readily.

Comment: Is the person refusing the candy bar in order to be polite or because, despite wanting it, they know they shouldn't eat it (New Year's resolution, commitment to reduce sugar intake, and all that) ?

Comment: Maybe a question of 'good manners', for sure an opinion-based issue.

Comment: There are different motivations for sure now you mention it.  I have a hard time describing it.  It's not a practical motivation like weight loss, because it doesn't have to be food - it could be a ticket to a show or something like that as well.  It could be about manners or being polite, but is refusing a gift polite? I don't know that I consider that good manners personally, but maybe to them it is.  It's almost like misplaced pride about not wanting to accept something.

Comment: I think how you describe it depends on a) the refuser's intent, and b) your perception of it.

Answer (score 3):

To describe this behavior, I would not emphasize the "falseness" of the refusal but the "appropriateness" with the following words:

> **courteous** (adj): very polite in a way that shows respect
>
> **decorous** (adj): correct and polite in a particular situation

I think these words are appropriate because this situation - assuming some social distance between the two parties - requires respect for **etiquette**.

Were there not social distance between the parties, we wouldn't stew about it. If my brother offers me a candy bar, I say nothing. I just take it, unwrap it, and devour it, wordlessly. This is, indeed, why I enjoy spending time with my brother.

Many cultures have more heavily prescribed rules for acceptance and refusal of offers, particularly of food and drink. Consider **[taarof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taarof#In_the_West)** in Persian culture, for example, or [the rules of etiquette in East Asian countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiquette_in_Asia#China_.28including_Hong_Kong.29_and_Taiwan). Many of these systems of etiquette require two refusals before an acceptance. Many English-speakers will behave similarly, although such rules haven't been so exactly codified (unlike our rules, say, for table-setting).

Answer (score 2):

The word for this is **dissemble**.

> dis·sem·ble verb \di-ˈsem-bəl\ : to hide your true feelings, opinions,
>   etc.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissemble)

Comment: That's a bit harsh. This term is normally reserved for more malignant manifestations, and suggests an air of hypocrisy. If that's what the OP means, fine, but I don't get that sense from the bare text above.

Comment: @Robusto I take the possession and fate of candy bars very seriously.

Comment: +1,When you dissemble, you disguise your true feelings behind a false appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Scandinavian.  In my neck of the woods, the behavior of ritual refusal is so prevalent (Minnesota) that often the polite reply is interrupted by "Don't be so Scandinavian, just take it!"  Both participants then chuckle.

We also use "French" to shame the arrogant.  "Oh, aren't we French!", or, "Where are you from, France?".

Again, this is just local stuff.

Comment: I think we're experiencing the same thing then because I'm in Minnesota as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would think such a refusal has to do with the closeness of the relationship  between the person offering and the person refusing.  But I am probably on the older side (80) of most people posting here and thus such a refusal would be somewhat common to me.
Many years ago I expressed a desire for an item that was almost immediately offered to me.  I was very embarrassed because I felt like I was asking for something from the giver, which I was not.  I refused the item, but was uncertain if that was correct or rude.

Comment: That's very true but it doesn't actually answer the question, which is whether there's a specific word for that embarrassing situation where you have to pretend you don't want the thing even though you really do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context, but the most common would be polite, or perhaps even formal.